# MVC5 ConfirmEmailAsync fails and DbEntityValidationException is thrown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project where the ApplicationUser has been modified due some design criteriums. As you can see below the property Student is required. So every ApplicationUser must have one Student. The idea behind this design is to seperate the login details of IdentityFramework from the Student.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IEntity
{
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateDeleted  { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

When a new user registers on the page. An email is send to his inbox. After receiving the email and trying to activate the token. An DbEntityValidationException is thrown and it says that the Student is a required field.

When debugging the code and the cursor reaches the catch, if I look back to UserManager I find the Student present and the boolean EmailConfirmed in ApplicationUser is on true, but not in the database.

Somewhere behind the scenes it doesn't get through to the SaveChanges.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        try
        {
            var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
            return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
            var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
            var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
            throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
        }
    }
```

If someone has any idea or had the same issue, please let me know!

Comment: Have you got error in `var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);` line? How was the `ApplicationUser` table layout in DB? Post error details and stack trace content to find out source of issue.